# Download and save GitHub issues via command line

Tags: bash, github, command-line, terminal, github-api

How can I download and save all GitHub issues of a certain repository via the command line (terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

This bash-script downloads the issues from the GitHub API and saves them as one YAML-file per issue:

```
count=0 http -a <username> -b \
https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo>/issues?state=all\&sort=created\&direction=asc \
| json -0 -a \
| while read -r line; \
do (( count++ )); echo $line | js-yaml > $count.yaml; done
```

For a full explanation check out:

http://adriansieber.com/download-github-issues-from-command-line

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the post)